# Will a mature animal companion with Haste get 2 actions when not commanded?

Tags: druid, actions, animal-companions, pathfinder-2e

I tried to do this in a game, but the GM said I couldn’t and became irate when I asked why.  He gave me an explanation that I didn’t think made sense.  But instead of saying after the game we’ll figure it out, he became irate.  Anyone have specific rules backing him up or why he is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. I think you may be dealing with 2 entirely different issues here: the rules question in the title, and a group-dynamics issue involving your GM. If you're interested in the answer to both, I'd suggest editing this question to focus on just the rules question, and possibly asking another separate question about the underlying issue with how your GM responded (though you should clearly identify what that underlying issue is/what you want help resolving with regard to it).

Answer (score 10):

### Background

[Animal Companions](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=149) are [Minions](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=109), and have different rules about how they act. The Druid's [Mature Animal Companion](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=322) Feat alters this, but not significantly.

[Haste](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=147) grants the [Quickened](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=32) Condition with the restriction that the extra action can be used as a Strike or Stride.

### Strict RAW

Minions don't have a *turn* and will never benefit from Quickened.

> You gain 1 additional action at the start of your turn each round. [...]

Mature Animal Companion gives them an *action*, not a *turn*, so this does not alter this.

### It is a little grey

The text on Minions does include some ambiguity.

> [...] A creature with this trait can use only 2 actions per turn and can’t use reactions. Your minion acts on your turn in combat...

This seems to indicate **your turn** is when they can use 2 actions "per turn", but could indicate that they do have a "turn" that is a portion of your turn.

If a GM rules that they do have a legitimate *turn*, Quickened/Haste would grant *any* Minion 1 action at the start of it's controller's turn regardless of if they were ordered about. Of course, most Minions would "do nothing" with this action (pending GM adjudication), but Mature Animal Companions do get to use an action without instruction and therefore could use both actions.

---

### My recommendation

A lot of game systems break down if Minions are considered to not have turns. They should gain/lose actions from Conditions. Each GM should rule for their own table if the action is usable without direction or if the single action from Mature is a more specific circumstance than normal Action allocation and doesn't qualify for the bonus action (essentially the Mature Animal Companion gets 1 Action or 3 if commanded).

If this comes up at my table, I'll rule that the Minion/AC does get to use the Quickened action. My justification? If the party bothered to *Haste a non-PC*, then that's a significant enough investment that they should get the *normal* returns (one additional action each round). It hardly ruins balance as the AC should, statistically, be falling behind what that action could do for a full PC and theoretically is more fun for the player(s) involved. If its a common tactic and affects balance more than expected, then that just means that I'd need to add in a Creature -1 or -2 from the party to offset the difference, occasionally.

Comment: I do think @Elrond Smith's answer raises a good point; ruling animal companions as not having turns would have a lot of oddball effects.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't thinking about any of the other things that are tied to 'turns'. I'll look into it again and try to improve this

Comment: Your justification for giving it quickend breaks it Haste is heightened to 7th level

Comment: Not at all. The action is still the one action given by the spell, and as noted in the comment to your related answer, there is opportunity cost in the form of placement, initiative adjustments if you're waiting for Haste, and possibly reaching the restrictive limit on number of targets for Haste even at 7th depending on group size, composition, and even NPC's present.

Answer (score 3):

Ruling that animal companions do not have a turn would have a lot of unintended consequences such as with effects that only take place at the beginning or end of your turn.

I think if the developers did not want animal companions to have turns it would be explicit.

Examples of effects that would not affect them -
Persistent damage, CloudKill and many others...

Comment: Hello, and welcome to RPG.SE! Make sure to take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and visit the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) with any questions!

You raise some good points; adding some rule quotations might help your answer. If you specifically found an effect that references Animal Companions and the start or end of their turn, I think you would have a very excellent answer.